# Finding list of bus stops and what is next

Tags: maps, google, ios, route, transit

First of all apilogies if this is already discussed. I am a low vision person and there is only so much time I can spend searching for information as it is stressful on the eyes. I spent considerable amount of time before posting here.

As I stopped driving and started taking public transit, I am feeling the need for an app that is customized for my needs. While on the bus, it is hard to either look out and find where I am and if the bus does announce the next intersection, it is most of the times, impossible to hear. So, what I need is an app that tells me what is the next stop as the bus travels along the route. It would also be helpful if it announced the next intersection/street. This would help me in figuring out when to pull the cord to request a stop.

What sdk/api would help in this? I am looking at google maps api or anything that I can use to integrate with the app on iphone. Given that this is for a low vision person, the visual map is less important. What I plan to do is, use the info that I get from the maps and feed it to the iOS accessibility framework to convert to voice. Any help and pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which city? Boston has http://catchthebusapp.com/ for Apple devices

Comment: Since you asked the above question and Mapperz original response (in 2013), many more cities now Public Transport information now available. Could you tell me which city(s) you are interested in?